# Blocking googleapis.com at browser level in enterprise policy

Tags: browser, dns, chromium, policies

I'm trying to set some Chromium browser policies as outlined in [Set up policies](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start/) for a enterprise Linux environment. Some policies are straight forward, however, I have found out from DNS logs that when chromium browser is opened, it does a lot of DNS look-ups such as the following.

- accounts.google.com
- googleapis.com
- google.com
- optimizationguide-pa.googleapis.com
- update.googleapis.com

I need to block these at a browser level using policies. A list of all the supported polices are listed [here](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/). I have tried using the `URLBlocklist` policy and providing a list of the above mentioned look-ups (using `www` or `https` or `http`). Nothing seem to work.

Any idea how this can be achieved via policies.

Note that I have already set some relevant policies, which are as follows. Nevertheless the look-ups still occur.

`DefaultSrarchProviderEnabled : false`
`AutoFillEnabled : false`
`AutofillAddressEnabled: false`
`SearchSuggesteEnabled: false`

Comment: Not an answer, but you should know that many websites and web apps rely on connections to www.googleapis.com for user authentication with Firebase.